# Предупреждение "file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: Время ожидания соединения истекло" при авторизации

Tags: php

Есть готовый скрипт магазина с возможностью авторизации через соц. сети с помощью [ulogin.ru](http://ulogin.ru).

При попытке авторизации появляется предупреждение:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://ulogin.ru/token.php?token=7a6b15688681e0ab6f4f4782c4675923&host=denisencko-nicki.myjino.ru): failed to open stream: Время ожидания соединения истекло in /home/users/d/denisencko-nicki/domains/denisencko-nicki.myjino.ru/index.php on line 148

Вот отрывок из файла *index.php*:

```
147: $token = $_POST['token'];
148: $s = file_get_contents('http://ulogin.ru/token.php?token=' . $token . '&host=' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
149: $user = json_decode($s, "true");
150: $uid = $user["uid"];
```

В чём заключается проблема, и как её решить?

[Ссылка](http://denisencko-nicki.myjino.ru/) на сайт с этой проблемой.

Comment: А с того компа вы нормально можете достучаться до `ulogin.ru`? Попробуйте выполнить `wget http://ulogin.ru/token.php?token=123` и посмотрите ответ. У вас может достучаться не может до него и проблему с сетью надо искать, а не в коде . И попробуйте `CURL` использовать, он более информативен по ошибкам и время сократит. К тому же, для `file_get_contents` еще бы `context` передавать неплохо было бы.

Comment: А у Вас полноценный оплаченный аккаунт на этом хостинге, или тестовый бесплатный?